# call PyErr_SetString twice without clearing

Tags: c++, exception, cpython

I have a C++ function to parse python strings:

```
std::string parse_string(PyObject* py_string) { 
  std::string out; 
  if (!PyString_Check(py_string)) { 
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"expected a string");
    return out; 
  }
  out = PyString_AsString(py_string); 
  return out; 
}
```

I'm calling the function from a python wrapper:

```
PyObject* some_func(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) { 
// ...
  std::string my_first_string = parse_string(first_py_string);
  if (PyErr_Occurred()) { 
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"more verbose error for this string"); 
    return 0; 
  }
  std::string my_second_string = parse_string(second_py_string);
  if (PyErr_Occurred()) { 
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"some other error for this string"); 
    return 0; 
  }
// ...
}
```

This will throw a python exception as desired, but I'm worried about calling `PyErr_SetString` again to give the more verbose message. Will it cause a leak?

Comment: @littleadv In python, not C++. When a python function sets the exception string and returns 0, it raises an exception.

Comment: hmmm so maybe remove the C++ tag?:)

Comment: @littleadv I'm reluctant to, since this is not C code like the CPython tag would lead one to believe. But if it seems very clear that it should be removed I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python Extension Patterns](https://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html), it's okay to set exceptions multiple times in a single call stack. Only the last one will be set and thrown when you return to Python.

```
The other thing to note is that if there are multiple calls 
to PyErr_SetString only the last one counts:

static PyObject *_raise_error_overwrite(PyObject *module) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "FORGOTTEN.");
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "ERROR: _raise_error_overwrite()");
    assert(PyErr_Occurred());
    return NULL;
}
```